# Unity3D Bullet Tracers

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

I'm currently working on implementing the elusive bullet tracer to my FPS. It isn't going so well.
  a. The tracers align themselves off of the barrel of the Raycast area
  b. They all aim themselves in the same direction, no matter where I point my cursor
  This is the formula I'm currently using to calculate where the tracers should go.

```
        fwd.x += Random.Range(-accuracy, accuracy);
        fwd.y += Random.Range(-accuracy, accuracy);
        fwd.z += Random.Range(-accuracy, accuracy);
        Instantiate(tracer, transform.position, Quaternion.LookRotation((fwd - transform.position).normalized));
```

The code is Unityscript (js). Thank you!

Comment: theres nothing wrong with that code. Post the code that makes the tracers

Comment: There is no code that makes the tracers. The tracer is a prefab with a Shuriken particle system on it. The tracer system is instantiated just fine, but in a wrong direction and off alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Quaternion.LookRotation((fwd - transform.position).normalized)` needs to be `Quaternion.LookRotation(fwd.normalized)`

Comment: Thank you so much! The particles are still off-center, but I guess I'll just have to hack it (literally).